# Performance issues with game

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

My game lags in single player mode, often to the point that it crashes. If it doesn't crash, it gets to so few FPS that when I right-click doors to close them, they close and then immediately open again, and when i right-click to place blocks, instead of placing one the game will place several... Usually only 2, but lately (and especially since the snapshot 12w24a) it will place 3. The most i've ever seen is 4 blocks placed by one click, that has only happened once.

I have tried to download the Optifine that everyone is talking about...all I can find is blogs about it and sites with possibly flesh-eat viruses. I may have ruined my computer in the last 10 minutes trying to download it.

My reader distance is already set to short, that used to help but since the snapshot it doesn't make any differance. I've taken off the clouds and basically everything else you can do from in-game to make it run better, and it just seems to be getting worse. In fact, since the update when I first load the level it's only about 5 chunks big and then immediately drops off into a giant abyss in ever direction. I have to wait several minutes for it to load a full level and replace the void, and when it does it moves me back to the spawn and takes away anything I have done. Also since the snapshot, animals and blocks will randomly freeze for an unspecified amount of time and I can run around but not interact with anything.

Someone please help - I love minecraft, but it's getting literally unplayable.

Comment: You can find the official Optifine release [here](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/249637-125-optifine-hd-c2-fps-boost-hd-textures-aa-af-and-much-more/)

Comment: @Austin Are you playing on a server?  If yes, then the problem is in the connection between you and the game world.  I've never heard of these kinds of issues existing offline, but they're incredibly common when playing online with a spotty connection somewhere.

Comment: I have had the same issue with the snapshots, but no issues at all with the official release. (Well, my computer is horrible, so I still frequently get 4 fps...)

Answer (score 4):

I can see how a lot of your problems are caused by the new game mechanics in the recent snapshots. Singleplayer is now multiplayer, it's basically a LAN server. This is very pointless in my opinion, but I believe there is a reason, whatever it may be. Now your game is running a LAN listen server and a client, which may amplify performance issues.

> Also since the snapshot, animals and blocks will randomly freeze for
>   an unspecified amount of time and I can run around but not interact
>   with anything.

This specifically is because of the new multiplayer-singleplayer thing.

---

I would suggest going back to the recent version of the game, not the snapshots. If the snapshots ever become the full game, you may have a problem. Not to sound mean here, but, a lot of people foolishly think all performance issues involving games can be fixed. This is not true. If you get the chance, get a new computer. That's the only real definite solution to performance issues.

Also, as [neosatan's answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/74019/27689) mentions don't use mods or texture packs. That will definitely slow down your game.

Comment: *"This is very pointless in my opinion, but I believe there is a reason"* - If this is true, the reason would almost certainly be to simplify coding, so that some features would not have to be recoded for both single- and multi-player.  It also reduces bugs *(in the long run)*, since jeb would no longer have to consider how a change would affect single- and multi-player separately.

Comment: Not to sound mean here, but, a lot of people foolishly think all performance issues involving games can be fixed. This is not true. If you get the chance, get a new computer. That's the only real definite solution to performance issues. 

+1 for that

Comment: It's not pointless, for the reasons given above, plus it also enables the 'Open to LAN' option. Games have been doing this forever - start any Quake 3 based title up, and watch the console output, for example.

Answer (score 1):

I have to tell that I installed minecraft on some weak laptops, and when switching between single and multi player I noticed that on version 1.2.5 sometimes its better to play on a multiplayer server then on singleplayer. That is my personal experience.

Also installing OptiFine can help. In my case it pull from 18 FPS on weak laptop to 28 FPS, so it is a playable amount. I could probably squeeze some more FPS but It wasn't my laptop so I didn't put much effort in that. I think that you can disable tons of options to improve the speed. Optifine also unloads unused chuncks.

Next thing is that snapshots tent to have tons of bugs. I prefere play on official versions, and wait for complete version.
Another thing is texturepacks. If You are playing with a high resolution texturepack (for example 256x256) then performance will be lower. switch to 16x16. This is because higher resolution will require more memory and GPU cycles to render.

If you still have a low frame-rate after all these steps then thats most likely because of your lack of proper hardware and you will have to upgrade your hardware in order to play minecraft.